# How to pass ng-model by reference?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to get an custom input text. This is my view

```
<div>
    <span>{{label}}</span>
    <input type="text" class="{{class}}" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-style="width?{width: width + 'px'}:{}" ng-model="model"/>
</div>
```

and this is my controller

```
    angular.module('inputText', [])
        .directive('inputText', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: true,
                scope: {
                    width: '@',
                    label: '@',
                    class: '@',
                    placeholder: '@',
                    model: '@'
                },
                controller: 'InputCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'inputText.html'
            };
        })
        .controller('InputCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        }]);
```

The problem is that I'm always getting somothing like the following error message:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'model' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{model}}] starting at [model}}].
```

My question is: How do I should pass the model by reference, in order to get something like:

```
<input-text label="When?" class="" placeholder="" icon="awesome-icon" width="150" model="{{when}}"></input-text>
```

Comment: first thing: remove the {{ }} in ng-model (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Comment: @EduardGamonal I've just noticed it, but I've done without success. I don't have error but the model in the directive isn't bound to the parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the model as `scope: { model: "=" }` (`=` means 2-way binding) and use:

```
<input ... ng-model="model" />
```

in the template.

Remember not to use first level properties: I.e. do something like this:

```
<input-text ... model="form.when"></input-text>
```

And **NOT** this:

```
<input-text ... model="when"></input-text>
```

In all cases the `{{when}}` is wrong, it will not be 2-way bound.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried with "&", "@" and "=" and finally the problem was defining the ng-model in the parent wiew. I had used model="when" instead of model="form.when" the object notation made the difference